# Deleting file from static method error: Access to the path ... is denied

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, exception, delete-file

My host swears the ASPNet account has full access to the folder some photos reside in. I'm trying to delete a photo, here's the C#:

```
public static bool Delete(string pathAndFilename)
{
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(pathAndFilename);
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

(in the full code, there's a try catch in there, and bool return values)

Update: this is happening on local development box too now. Here's what I have been able to try.

I put the current user into the ViewBag, and show it on the page.

```
ViewBag.Account = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

On the dev box, it shows my currently logged in user account, which has full control of every file and folder in the project.

I checked open files, the photo I'm trying to delete wasn't open.

Will try to capture more detailed exceptions. Thanks for the ideas so far!

Comment: rest assured it has nothing to do with being in a static method

Comment: Thank you... I can rule that out. Appreciate that.

Comment: Access denied also means that another process is using the file. Same error for two things, make sure you are disposing `Stream`s that access the file.

Comment: How about using `UnauthorizedAccessException` ?

Answer (score 0):

IUSR? That should be the NETWORK SERVICE or the ASPNET account (depending on the version of IIS)

edit: also there is no reason to give IUSR full access. It only needs read access.

Comment: Only Read-privileges to _delete_ a File?

Comment: Only read for the IIS user that is NOT the user that his application is running under.

Comment: Yes, sorry... I meant ASPNet user, darn dyslexia!

Comment: The checking what is in `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. I highly suspect it is NETWORK SERVICE and not ASPNET.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a fully-qualified path ("C:\foo") or if the string isn't recognizable as a path, it'll throw an HttpException.

It would be helpful if you described exactly what you're seeing.